# Trying to run processing in atom, Getting error

Tags: java, linux, processing, atom-editor

So I am trying to run Processing 3.5.4 on Atom instead of using the official ide (because it looks ugly). And I am getting one main error when I am trying to run code on atom.

> Failed to spawn command `processing-java`. Make sure `processing-java` is installed and on your PATH

Furthur information

I am using manjaro linux 21.2.1
Processing IDE is installed through flatpak.
I have the three processing packages : processing, processing-autocomplete, processing-lanaguage.
I have also tried doing `sudo ln -s /path/to/processing/processing-java /usr/local/bin/` but , as I have no idea where processing-java is, it didn't work(I have looked it up online but there is little to no information about this).

Comment: You can find the path by `which` command:
`which processing-java`

Comment: Also take a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1167893/274623

Comment: I did `which processing-java` and I got this message `which: no processing-java in (/home/yc/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/yc/.dotnet/tools:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)`

Comment: As I mentioned in the second comment, flow the link and find the install location of the flatpack and make sure the `process` has been installed!

Comment: First of all, that is an ubuntu forum which is different from my os.
and second of all, the process itself is installed. What I am trying to find is a specific file called `processing-java` as I need it to run .pde files in the atom IDE but what you're saying is to make sure its installed?

Comment: :) Yea I see, your OS is different but not your package manager (`Flatpack`), and as the Manjaro documentation, the installation path is the same! do something run `flatpack list` to just make sure that the `process` itself has been installed!

Comment: I did what you said and the process is installed. But I didn't find what I need in the folder where processing is installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to run .pde files on this editor called Atom IDE. And it's asking me for a file called processing-java. I have no idea where this file is and need help in finding it.